# I need to call .bat file from Powershell script

Tags: powershell

We are migrating perl script to powershell script.
In Perl the code is as shown below

```
$rc='D:\\EmailConnector\\run.bat> $EmailConnector_log;';
```

I tried as shown below but not working

```
StartProcess "cmd.exe" "/c D:\EmailConnector\run.bat> $EmailConnector_log"
```

When I tried as shown below the .bat script ran, but I want to update the log file. Could you help me on this.

```
StartProcess run.bat -workingdirectory "D:\EmailConnector"
```

The .bat file consist of jar file for email functionality. But we want to get log in log file.

Comment: I wrote an answer, however, your question is not clear enough, the log file should be the input for the run.bat? or it just need to run from the d:\emailconnector folder?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`), like this:

```
& 'D:\EmailConnector\run.bat' > $EmailConnector_log
```

The return value of the batch script is automatically put into the variable [`$LastExitCode`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx).

Comment: **& 'D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat' >$emailconnecter_log** i tried like this and got an error message as run.bat : log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. At D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\Output\Test_Eamil.ps1:108 char:3 + & <<<< 'D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat' >$emailconnecter_log + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (log4j:ERROR set...e) call failed.:String) [], RemoteException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: That error comes from the code in your batch file and is unrelated to this question. Please post a new question with the content of the batch file and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```
Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList '/c','D:\EmailConnector\run.bat' -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector"
```

or this one if you need another argument for logfile

```
Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList '/c','D:\EmailConnector\run.bat','EmailConnector_log' -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, since there are no spaces in the path, you can just execute the batch file directly from PowerShell:

```
D:\EmailConnector\run.bat > $EmailConnector_log
```

This is one of the advantages of PowerShell being both a "shell" and a "scripting language".  Execution of batch, cmd, vbs, exe files is straightforward - usually.  Parameter passing can be an issue but these days that is easily solved with the stop parsing operator: `--%`.